# Overleaf writing algorithm giving errors

Tags: algorithms

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{usenix,epsfig,endnotes}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\begin{document} 
\begin{keyword}
\end{keyword}
sdfdsf
\end{keyword}
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{PPO} 
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \For {$iteration=1,2,\ldots$}
            \For {$actor=1,2,\ldots,N$}
                \State Run policy $\pi_{\theta_{old}}$ in environment for $T$ time steps
                \State Compute advantage estimates $\hat{A}_{1},\ldots,\hat{A}_{T}$
            \EndFor
            \State Optimize surrogate $L$ wrt. $\theta$, with $K$ epochs and minibatch size $M\leq NT$
            \State $\theta_{old}\leftarrow\theta$
        \EndFor
    \end{algorithmic} 
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Game Theory Controller}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \For {Every time step}
        \State Calculate target seeking command $\mathbf{x}_{tsCmd}$ (Eq.: 3.12)
        \For {All map measurements from $\mathbf{x}_{Map}$}
        \State Denormalize measurement (Eq.: 3.14)
        \State Add margin of safety (Eq.: 3.15)
        \State Calculate altitude difference $\Delta h_{ObsSafe_{j}}$ to aircraft (Eq.: 3.16)
        \If {$\Delta h_{ObsSafe_{j}}>0$}
        \State Add measurement to set of critical measurements $\mathcal{M}_{crit}$ (Eq.: 3.17)
        \EndIf
        \EndFor
        \For {All measurements in $\mathcal{M}_{crit}$}
        \State Calculate local obstacle avoidance vector (Eq.: 3.20)
        \EndFor
        \State Sum over all local avoidance vectors (Eq.: 3.22)
        \State Transform to global coordinate frame to receive $\mathbf{x}_{oaCmd}$ (Eq.: 3.23)
        \State Calculate obstacle avoidance weight $w_{oa}$ based on critical zone weight (Eq.: 3.24)
        \State Calculate target seeking weight $w_{ts}$ as $1-w_{oa}$ (Eq.: 3.13)
        \State Calculate command vector $\mathbf{x}_{HSaCmd}=w_{oa}\mathbf{x}_{oaCmd}+w_{ts}\mathbf{x}_{tsCmd}$ (Eq.: 3.11)
        \EndFor
    \end{algorithmic} 
\end{algorithm} 
\end{document}
```

Whenever I add algorithm, or algpseudocode  to usepackage to have option of writing begin{algorithm} I am getting errors at begin{keyword}

```
You have created an environment (using \begin{…} and \end{…} commands) which is not recognized. Make sure you have included the required package for that environment in your preamble, and that the environment is spelled correctly.
```

Comment: I did not have the `usenix` package but of I delete that then `keyword` is not defined, so unless your local `usenix` package defines a keyword environment that environment hasn't been defined. That is unrelated to overleaf. or algorithms.

Comment: unrelated but don't load `epsfig` (I wrote that in1994 as a legacy package for latex2.09 documents that were old then)

Comment: In your example, there is one `\begin{keywords}` but two`\end{keywords}`.